# Delay the loading of an Ember View template until completion of AJAX request

Tags: ember.js

It doesn't look like it is possible to delay the load of a template until a response comes back from an AJAX request inside the willInsertElement property of an Ember View?

I would like to load jquery-ui.min.js before the template renders.

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create()

App.TestView = Ember.View.create
    tagName: 'div'
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile '<div>This is a view</div>'
    willInsertElement: ->
      $.ajax({
        url: "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"
        dataType: "script"
        async: false
        success: (data, textStatus, jqxhr) ->
          console.log data
          console.log textStatus
          console.log jqxhr.status
          console.log "Load was performed."
      });
    didInsertElement: ->
      console.log 'the element was inserted'

App.TestView.append()
```

I'm finding that the didInsertElement runs before the AJAX request is finished.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you want to achieve in the end? Assure that `jquery-ui` is available before the view is inserted?

- You could append your view in the `success` callback then, see http://jsfiddle.net/RgcJA/
- I haven't tested your code, but is `$.getScript` executed asynchronously? Have you tried setting `async: false`?

Comment: I changed the question to use $.ajax as $.getScript is just a higher level abstraction.  I just tried setting aync: false and that doesn't work.  But I believe you are correct that I may need append the view in the success callback.

Answer (score 0):

You can try binding the visible property of your view to a variable and then toggling that variable when your file upload has completed.

You will also have to start the file upload outside `willInsertElement`